# Comparing model fits of different splits of the same dataset (with AIC)

Tags: goodness-of-fit, aic, model-comparison

I have a large set of panel data (~500 000 observations for about 1000 units) where I suspect both intercepts and coefficients can vary over the units observed. These units have a kind of class system which is why the can be divided into different groups, which can be divided into different subgroups etcetera. I am trying to find a model that best fits the data, allowing for heterogeneity in coefficients and intercepts where needed. I am looking at a host of different approaches including mixed linear effects and fixed effects models.

One of my current approaches is the following: Estimate a fixed effects model for the entire dataset. Compute some goodness of fit statistics like $R^2$, $RMSE$ and $AIC$. Divide the dataset into 5 pieces, estimate a fixed effect model for each of those pieces, compute GOF statistics again. If necessary divide these pieces into 3-4 pieces each, etcetera. It can be observed that for example RMSE and (adjusted) R^2 are higher when splitting the dataset into 5 pieces, lending credibility to the hypothesis of heterogeneity across units.

My question is how can AIC (or another information criterion) be used to compare these differents sets of models. Is it for example possible to sum them or use the AIC formula to compute an 'AIC-like statistic' for a set of of models?

If you have any other suggestions on how to compare sets of models in this manner or any papers on the subject I would also be happy to read them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you are excluding the use of random effects?

Comment: I am not, that is also one of the approaches I'm looking at. More specifically, I am allowing for random effects for a set of variables in my mixed linear effects model. That is also one of the reasons I am trying to compute some sort of AIC, so I can compare the performance of the mixed linear effects model with the performance of a 'set' of fixed effects models. Complete random effects is of course also an option, but I have reason to suspect that some coefficients should be the same across units.

Comment: With a small tweak to the process you are describing, you could estimate cross validation error for each model: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)

Comment: Alright thank you, that is a very useful way to compare model performance. I'm kind of curious as to what you mean by 'small tweak', though. Seems to me that cross-validation has to be just done separately in every model?

Comment: I mean that you are already splitting your dataset and fitting models to each. That's a large part of what cross-validation is, though of course you need to treat the split datasets quite differently.

Comment: Ah that is true of course, although the way I am splitting datasets now (across units) is not usable for cross-validation. Splitting over time would work though and is certainly a useful measure of model performance.